# Подсказки при написании кода в Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Как включить подсказки при написании кода как на скрине? У меня такого нет:

[image: скриншот]

Comment: оно включено по умолчанию. скорее всего, у вас компьютер немного слабенький. если у вас ноут - убедитесь, что он в "сбалансированном режиме питания" (энергосбережения на слабых ноутах может не всегда показывать подсказки)

Comment: Также, подсказки появляются, когда idea определила соответствующие пакеты с классами. В вашем случае это стандартный jdk.

Comment: нажми ctrl + Space

Answer (score 0):

в правом верхнем углу(либо в панельке снизу, где кодировка и т.п.) будет нарисована батарейка это означает что у тебя включен "Power save mode", вырубай его(просто нажми на батарейку, что бы был глаз нарисован) и тогда подсказки снова включатся